# Unable to access values of array passed from managed to unmanaged code

Tags: c#, com, marshalling, com-interop, unmanaged

***What i am trying to do*** :

i am trying to call a method written in a ATL COM server (a dll basically) from a c# client.i am trying to pass a c-style 1-dimensional array by reference to the method and return the first-index value of the array.Method goes like this:

**Function defnition in calc class(C++):**

```
    STDMETHODIMP CCalc::ConformantCArray(int ArrSize, int** ptr,int* res)
      {
        (*ptr)++;//***REFERENCE 2*** 
        *res = *(*ptr);//***REFERENCE 1*** 
        return S_OK;
      }
```

**Corresponding idl declaration**

```
    HRESULT ConformantCArray([in] int ArrSize, [in] int** CArray,[out,retval] int* res) ;
```

With help from msdn articles i found that a interop can be generated and modified to marshal the parameters appropriately between managed and unmanaged code.I have generated a Interop out of this using TLBIMP and dis-assembled the generated interop dll to find the following signature:

**Signature Before Modification (IL code):**

```
    instance int32  ConformantCArray([in] int32 ArrSize,[in] native int CArray)
```

I modified the IL code as i am  passing an 1-d array by reference ,the reference part was missing in the interop generated and modified it accordingly(refered from a book on interoperability).

**Signature After Modification (IL code):**

```
    instance int32  ConformantCArray([in] int32 ArrSize,[in] native int & CArray)
```

Now i am calling this method by pinning the an array using ***GCHANDLE*** class to pin the array and provide unmanaged acces to it via an **INTPTR**   and reading the return value back in an int variable **VAL** .I chose to pin the object as i was worried if the managed array pointer would get copied to an unmananged stack and if copied it would copy only the first value that is referenced by the array pointer because it is nothing but the address of first value which would result in fetching only Zero-index value of array(Please correct me if my idea of copying values from managed stack,heap to unmanaged stack,heap is wrong ).Sounds fair enough right?

**C# Client Code:**

```
            int val = 0;
            int[] CArray = {1,2,3};
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(CArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            int ArrSize = 2;

            try
            {

                val = obj.ConformantCArray(ArrSize, ref ptr);
            }
            finally
            {

                if (handle.IsAllocated)
                    handle.Free();
            }
```

Now comes the end to my long explanantion of the scenario as i am about to pose the Problem.

**Problem i face:**

if you see the code in the first code block that is the method itself i am returning the first-index value which is supposed to return ***2***(Look in reference 1 of code block), But instead It returns a garbage value **-14758585**.

**But:**
If i return the zero-index value of the array that is without the code ***(*ptr)++;*** (Look in reference 2 of code block).The returned value is **1** as expected.So i am deducing the only the zero-index value has been available to the unmanaged code .***If so why? And how can i solve this issue?*** i want to be able to acess all the values of the array on the server side .

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `size_is` somewhere in this IDL? (also, `(*ptr)++;` sounds dangerous and doesn't respect the contract of not modifying anything, implied by `[in]`).

Comment: My advice: Why not use safe arrays for interacting between .Net and COM?

Comment: ONE: i am not using a size_is(which specifies the relation between first and second parameter) i am not really interested in the length of the array ,i only want to acees the differenet elements of the array.Will that be a problem if i dont mention size_is.

Comment: Two:This is only a test that i am doing ,but i actually have to implement it on a an already existing com server that contains c-style arrays.Also does specifying the second parameter as out allow me to to do (*ptr)++ correctly ?.correctly in the sense go to the next adress of array whic is 32 bits away?

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem in the code.  You are dead in the water when COM decides to marshal the call, your IDL is not good enough to bring that to a good end.  Ensure that your test program has the [STAThread] attribute on its Main() entrypoint.

Comment: @chandu There's a difference between "accesssing the next element of the array" and "changing the array's pointer for no reason and without asking to do it". Instead of `(*ptr)++; *res = **ptr;`, you should do `int* indexedPointer = *ptr + 1; *res = *indexedPointer;`. ...or even better, `*res = (*ptr)[1];`.

Comment: @mmmmmmmm There is no reason ,just with the curiosity if it would fail that way so i can know why.

Comment: @Medinoc i tried with safe arrays and it is working fine .But i want to work with c-style arrays too ,And i have made some changes to code to go with simple array indices  instead of nested pointers,when i was debugging i found the that only first value of the array is being copied to a different location and it's adress  is being passed,i will update the code soon